# Estimation cardinality of certain classes of sets in $\mathbb{N}^{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Consider the following sets in $\mathbb{N}^{n}$
$$
F_{n} := \{ (x_1,..,x_n) \in \mathbb{N}^{n}: \sum_{i=1}^{i=n}x_i \ge A_n, \quad \max_{1\le i \le n}x_i \le B_n\}
$$
where for simplicity one can choose $A_n,\, B_n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $nB_n \ge A_n \ge B_n$.

The question is how to give a sharp estimation of cardinality of $F_{n}$? More specifically I
want to choose $A_n,\, B_n \to +\infty$ is $o(n)$ i.e $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{A_n + B_n}{n} = 0,\, \lim_{n\to+\infty}A_n = \lim_{n\to+\infty}B_n = +\infty$ and control the cardinality of $F_n$ as
$$
\# F_n \le e^{o(n)},\quad i.e. \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln \# F_n}{n} = 0
$$
Is it possible to achieve the cardinality control above? I am not familiar with combinatorics and I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this cannot be done because
$$
[\frac{A_n}{n},B_n]^{n} \subset F_n
$$
so the cardinality has a lower bound
$$
\# F_n \ge (B_n - \frac{A_n}{n})^{n}
$$
and $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\ln \# F_n}{n} \ge \limsup_{n\to+\infty}\ln B_n = +\infty$.